# el-checkbox cannot be set checked with jest or at least no change on v-model

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, jestjs, element-ui

I'm setting up some tests for my vuejs website. I'm using [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/). I'm trying jest on my connection page. I have a checkbox linked to a "remember me". I'd to check it and check if the value of the v-model changed.

Unfortunately, it doesn't.

In my connection file, I've the checkbox :

```
...
  <el-checkbox v-model="connectionForm.rememberme"></el-checkbox>
...
```

And the rememberme variable :

```
...
  data() {
    return {
      connectionForm: {
        ...
        rememberme: false
      },
...
```

My test file :

```
describe('Connection', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Connection)

  it('checkbox click', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.connectionForm.rememberme).toBe(false)

    expect(wrapper.contains('el-checkbox')).toBe(true)
    const elCheckbox = wrapper.find('el-checkbox')

    elCheckbox.setChecked(true)
    expect(wrapper.vm.connectionForm.rememberme).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

```sh
 FAIL  frontend/components/user/sessions/New.test.js
  Connexion
    ✓ has a el-button (4ms)
    ✕ checkbox click (10ms)

  ● Connexion › checkbox click

    [vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setChecked() cannot be called on this element

      26 | 
    > 27 |     elCheckbox.setChecked(true)
         |                ^
      28 |     expect(wrapper.vm.connexionForm.rememberme).toBe(true)
      29 |   })
      30 | })
```

[doc checkbox](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox#checkbox-group-events)

So, I changed the setChecked(true) with a .trigger('click'), still nothing. So, I changed 'click' to 'change', but still not working...

```sh
 FAIL  frontend/components/user/sessions/New.test.js
  Connexion
    ✓ has a el-button (4ms)
    ✕ checkbox click (10ms)
  ● Connexion › checkbox click

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      27 |     elCheckbox.trigger('change')
    > 28 |     expect(wrapper.vm.connectionForm.rememberme).toBe(true)
         |                                                  ^
      29 |   })
      30 | })
      31 |
```

If found somewhere this :

```
    elCheckbox.element.selected = true
```

But changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just had to add

```
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
Vue.use(ElementUI)
```

Then, I changed in my test all the "el-button" to "button", "el-checkbox" to "input" etc (better do it with ID)

Answer (score 1):

Yes

`wrapper.find('.el-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').setChecked(true)`

would have worked cuz el-checkbox itself has the checkbox input wrapped inside it (as one of its children) and this api seems to work on the checkbox input element. Ref: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setchecked.